# Hashtable slow to add values?

Tags: c#, collections, hashtable

I am currently using a Hashtable to store a list of unique identifiers and associated data, all of which is read in from a file.

The length of this data file can very greatly, from 1 entry to several hundred thousand.  I've noticed a significant slowdown in the speed of adding entries to the Hashtable once it gets past about 50,000 entries.

I think setting the initial capacity might help, but obviously I can't know this number since the data is read from a file.  Can anyone suggest a way to speed up adding a lot of entries, or is this behavior pretty normal?

edit: Right now I am just using a Hashtable.  I think it should probably be Dictionary<string, MyDataObject>, but that seems like a separate issue.

Comment: What class are you using? Dictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Comment: Have you tested whether setting a large capacity improves performance when there are lot of items to insert?

Comment: Setting the capacity should have no big impact - and should not be done when you don't know how many entries you will have (like anything between 1 and 100.000+).

Comment: I have not tested, but I agree with tanascius - I don't want to set the capacity to 100,000 if I will only have <10 items.

Comment: Do you read the file into memory before inserting it into the dictionary? Please do so (for test purposes), to make sure that really the insert is the problem.

Comment: I don't currently, but I have profiled the code, and the bottleneck is definitely Hashtable.Add().

Comment: Normally the capacity is growing by a factor (like 1.5) - so if you have a capacity of like 50,000 that gets too small it will be adjusted to 75,000.

Comment: I just tested a Dictionary<Int32, Int32> and inserted the numbers from 1 to 1.000.000. The average insert took a bit less then 100 nanoseconds on a quite slow desktop and I could only observe small fluctuations in insertion speed of less then a factor two probably caused by resizing the backing store.

Comment: I guess I need to do something other than the default grow behavior.  I'm not seeing a way to change that factor in the documentation - is that correct?

Comment: Do not concentrate on the grow factor or the growing process at all. The dictionary is working, for 50,000 entries and much more ... Have a look at the surrounding code, even if you profiled.

Comment: I now switched to using a Hashtable and got slightly more then 1300 nanoseconds per insert over the range from 1 to 1.000.000 - this is 13 times slower. So my first suggestion, use or at least test Dictionary<TKey, TValue> and get some strong typing for free. Inserting only values from 1 to 10.000 yielded an average insertion time of about 350 nanoseconds. So I can confirm a slowdown of 3 to 4 (using very unscientific profiling code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](http://www.phase9studios.com/2008/01/08/DictionaryVSHashTable.aspx) for comparison of HashTables and dictionaries for large numbers of items.

Comment: I didn't think the difference would be so drastic - it looks like switching to a Dictionary would go a long way towards solving my problem.

However, I cannot test right now, but I suspect I would see the same kind of slowdown on a smaller scale with a Dictionary.

Comment: The comparison is nevertheless interesting, because it tests with 10,000,000 keys and a GUI as id. It takes ~6sec. So there should be no bottleneck for 50,000 entries ... That's why I think it could be the file rather than the insert ...

Comment: This benchmark is not very good because new GUIDs are generate inside the timed loop and GUID generation is slow compared to a hash table access. In a quick test I found that creating a new GUID takes about 6 times as long as an insert into Dictionary<Int32, Guid>.

Comment: OK, that is a problem - but not in this context. Inserting 10,000,000 entries in 6sec. with creating an additional GUID during time measurement is fast and should not result in a bottleneck.